# Regex for GString Token

Tags: regex, groovy

I have an ID in this format:

```
1.5.31.14.${CHANNEL}.${SLOT}
```

It's read in from a file as a string and I'm trying to replace ${} tokens with other variables.

However, when I run:

```
id.replaceAll("\${CHANNEL}", "3")
```

it will attempt to replace ${CHANNEL} with a value called

```
CHANNEL
```

within the function and throw an error.

I've been going crazy trying to figure out what RegEx I can use to replace

```
${CHANNEL} and ${SLOT}
```

in the ID.

If anybody has any suggestions, please let me know.

**EDIT:**

Here is the error:

```
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CARD for class: ConsoleScript91
```

**EDIT 2**
Here is the code I ran:

```
def id = '1.5.31.14.${CHANNEL}.${SLOT}' 
id = id.replaceAll('\${CHANNEL}', '3')
replaced = id.replaceAll('\${SLOT}', '2')
print replaced
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception thrown

java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0

${CHANNEL}

^

at java_lang_String$replaceAll$1.call(Unknown Source)

at ConsoleScript5.run(ConsoleScript5:2)
```

Comment: Have you tried placing these in single quotes so they don't evaluate as GStrings? `id.replaceAll('\${CHANNEL}', "3")`?

Comment: @Tom Yes, and it throws exactly the same error.

Comment: Weird, using single quotes _should_ prevent this behaviour. Are you sure the exception is thrown in the line where you attempt to `replaceAll`? Maybe `toString` is called earlier on a GString containing this character sequence? This is when GStrings are evaluated. Maybe somewhere in the code that reads the file?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized comments don't accept code formatting.  I edited my post to show what happens--it's actually a different error, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape both dollar sign `$` and curly braces `{}`. Mind the fact that `\` is a special character so it should be escaped itself:

```
def id = '1.5.31.14.${CHANNEL}.${SLOT}' 
replaced = id.replaceAll('\\$\\{CHANNEL\\}', '3').replaceAll('\\$\\{SLOT\\}', '2')
replaced2 = id.replaceAll(/\$\{CHANNEL\}/, '3').replaceAll(/\$\{SLOT\}/, '2')

assert replaced == '1.5.31.14.3.2'
assert replaced == replaced2
```

Comment: Or you can use slashy strings and not require the double escape `/\$\{CHANNEL\}/`

Comment: @tim_yates and Opal Thank you!!  This was frustrating me so much.